# The receiver does not accept payments in this Currency

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to execute chained payments in which the Primary recipient takes currency British Pounds (GBP). I am a secondary recipient on the transaction. My account is set up for USD, but does NOT block any currencies, as you can see:

[image]

Here is the exact error message: The receiver [************] does not accept payments in this Currency

Please help me understand why this is failing. Is there additional setup I need to do in  my account? Do I have to explicitly allow GBP? I cannot change my primary currency or else it may break other users of my system who send me USD payments as a secondary recipient.

Comment: does the primary recipient (& all other recipients) in the chain accept the currency used in the transaction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add GBP as a currency on your account:

Login to PP
Go to Profile -> My Money
Next to PayPal balance, hover over More and click Currencies
Select British Pound from the list and click Add Currency

Try the Chain Payment again.