# The receiver ........ does not accept payments in this Currency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, activemerchant

I'm trying to integrate Paypal Adaptive checkout using [Active Merchant](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant) and [active_paypal_adaptive_payment](https://github.com/jpablobr/active_paypal_adaptive_payment) gem.

I've exact same problem which is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239138/the-receiver-does-not-accept-payments-in-this-currency).I've done the process mentioned in the accepted answer but still getting the same issue.
I'm setting the `currency_code` as `GBP` but during checkout I'm getting following error in my nginx error log.

> the receiver ........  does not accept payments in this Currency.

I've enabled my GBP in my paypal account but still getting the same error.I've no idea what I need to do to have the successful transaction.

Thank you, Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure the receiver is also accept GBP as their primary currency on their PayPal account.